# jenkins replay button, search in pipeline code

Tags: jenkins, pipelining

I'm using the **Replay** button in Jenkins to tweak changes to pipeline scripts without committing them. When I use the browser's **search** function to locate a string that exists in the code, most of the time the browser can't find it. I observed this both in Firefox and Chrome. Is there a way of searching that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll in the Pipeline script viewer, the javascript for the page deletes any lines that aren't visible and adds any lines that are scrolling into view.  So as far as the browser search feature is concerned, the lines outside the viewable area don't exist.

However, you can expand the size of the code window by clicking and dragging the bottom (similar to the text boxes used to edit questions/answers on SuperUser and other SE sites).

Comment: That explains why the search sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, very frustrating when you don't understand the cause!